# NSSplitView splitter pane change notification

Tags: notifications, splitter, nssplitview

Hello I need to implement four views splitters like in Maya, 3ds max, Blender or other similar modeling tools. I use NSSplitView on Mac side of my editor and I need to know when user drags one pane to sync another pane.
Is there any way to get new size from one NSSplitView and sync another view to it? I have working code for Windows Forms in C# version of this editor, but I can't figure out how to do it on a Mac. Full source code is at http://github.com/filipkunc/opengl-editor-cocoa.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it with this code:

```
- (void)splitViewDidResizeSubviews:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSSplitView *splitView = (NSSplitView *)[notification object];
    NSView *topSubview0 = (NSView *)[[topSplit subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSView *topSubview1 = (NSView *)[[topSplit subviews] objectAtIndex:1];

    NSView *bottomSubview0 = (NSView *)[[bottomSplit subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSView *bottomSubview1 = (NSView *)[[bottomSplit subviews] objectAtIndex:1];

    if (fabsf([bottomSubview0 frame].size.width - [topSubview0 frame].size.width) >= 1.0f)
    {
        if (splitView == topSplit)
        {
            NSLog(@"topSplit");
            [bottomSubview0 setFrame:[topSubview0 frame]];
            [bottomSubview1 setFrame:[topSubview1 frame]];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"bottomSplit");
            [topSubview0 setFrame:[bottomSubview0 frame]];
            [topSubview1 setFrame:[bottomSubview1 frame]];
        }
    }
}
```